# How do I change Tkinter Button colour

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 3 buttons

```
playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text="PLAY",command=self.playsong,width=6,height=1,font=("Comic Sans MS",16,"bold"),fg="coral4",bg="sandy brown").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)

playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text="PAUSE",command=self.pausesong,width=8,height=1,font=("Comic Sans MS",16,"bold"),fg="coral4",bg="sandy brown").grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)

playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text="UNPAUSE",command=self.unpausesong,width=10,height=1,font=("Comic Sans MS",16,"bold"),fg="coral4",bg="sandy brown").grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=5)

playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text="STOP",command=self.stopsong,width=6,height=1,font=("Comic Sans MS",16,"bold"),fg="coral4",bg="sandy brown").grid(row=0,column=3,padx=10,pady=5)
```

But they are grey and not sandy brown?
How could I fix this?

[image: buttons]

Comment: I think it is because you are using the same variable for the buttons. Also, there are 4 buttons

Comment: What OS are you using? If it is MacOS, you might be out of luck because MacOS controls some of the button's settings and you can't change them.

Comment: This code is working correctly for me, don't know why it is not working for you

Comment: I'm on Mac os so...